# does every .exe file need a new project in Microsoft Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, makefile, visual-studio-express

My background is Linux and traditional makefiles.  I have a project where the makefile builds several dozen executables I can then run to perform tests against the library being developed.  This library is now ported to Windows.

**My question:**  In Microsoft Visual C++, do I have to create a new project for every individual test `.exe` file?  Or is there a way to create 1 project that will easily build all of the .exe files?  E.g., `test001.cpp` becomes `test001.exe`, `test002.cpp` becomes `test002.exe`, etc.

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.  Right now what I do is click on `File->Add->New Project...->Win32 Console Application->...` for every test executable.  But it would be nicer if all these test files could be built without a new project for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have one project per executable, but you can have multiple projects per Visual Studio "solution".

When you build a solution, all of its projects get built. If you need the projects to be built in a specific order within the solution, you can easily set up dependencies.

Comment: This and Adam's comment above confirms what I had discovered on my own.  One solution file, and many projects within that solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio in the normal fashion, then yes, each VS project (i.e. each `.vcproj` file) corresponds to exactly one output file (an executable, DLL, or static library).

You can also use Visual Studio with makefiles though, if you want.  Just write your makefile as usual, except the C++ compiler is the `cl.exe` in the VS binaries directory, the linker is `link.exe`, and of course all of the command line flags are completely different.  You can even set your VS project to use `make` instead of its built-in system, so you can still use the IDE for editing and debugging.

Comment: I started out with nmake.exe calling cl and link. But not being too familiar with the Windows side of things, messed things up when it came time to pick the right command-line parameters.  I'll stick to the visual builder for now and just create the multiple projects in my solution.